# Как задать правильную ссылку в сортировке Yii2

Tags: yii2, listview, сортировка

Я использую такой код для вывода позиций

```
echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $goods,
                    'itemView' => '_item',
                    'options' => [
                        'tag' => false,
                    ],
                    'sorter' => [
                        'attributes'=>['name'],
                        'linkOptions'=>['url'=>'/catalog']
                    ],
                    'layout' => "{sorter}\n{items}\n{pager}",
                ]);
```

Это я делаю на странице /catalog. И если нажать на сортировку, то ссылка будет вида /catalog/index?sort=name, а мне надо что бы было /catalog?sort=name. Параметр **'linkOptions'=>['url'=>'/catalog']** не помог. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

вероятно надо покопаться с настройками маршрутизации в web.php

мне кажется этот вариант
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439873/redirect-without-showing-default-action-index-yii